Are environment-specific Micronaut startup functions possible?
I am currently trying to solve an issue with a Micronaut project. For some background, I am using Kafka as an events broker. I want to fail fast when launching the application when a certain configuration property is not present - the topic for the Kafka client.
This is done by eagerly initialising @Singleton classes during startup (one of which is using the Kafka client), like so:
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    build(*args)
        .eagerInitSingletons(true)
        .start()
}

Which causes the application to error on startup if the topic property is not present:
@KafkaClient
interface StockClient {
    companion object {
        const val KAFKA_TOPIC = "\${kafka.topics.kafkaTopic}"
    }

    @Topic(KAFKA_TOPIC)
    fun publishEvent(event: KafkaEvent)
}

This works fine and does what I want, however when it comes to run tests, it eagerly initialises the client as one might expect and tries to connect to Kafka, which is not present for testing (and shouldn't be, not needed in this case) and thus fails to connect and causes the tests to fail. I have tried to get around this by using the Micronaut Test Resources plugin, but this causes issues in my CI/CD pipeline and I would like to avoid unnecessarily using it where it isn't needed.
My question is, is it possible to have an environment-specific application startup function main(), so that I can only eagerly initialise singletons when not in the test environment? Any suggestions for alternate ways of failing fast on a missing configuration property would also be greatly appreciated.
